# I can't get clinfo to show gpu or cpu

Tags: opencl, ubuntu-18.04, amd-gpu

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and have an RX 580 AMD GPU. I installed the pro drivers (19.10) and I installed OpenCL, but when I run `clinfo` it shows 0 platforms. How can I make it detect my GPU.

I had this issue with Ubuntu 16.04 as well and I was unable to get it to work with any of the AMD pro drivers or the regular ones.

Answer (score 13):

Ok I just ran

```
sudo apt install mesa-opencl-icd
```

and it fixed it. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Why does this seem to work? This is not mentioned in: https://dgpu-docs.intel.com/installation-guides/ubuntu/ubuntu-focal.html